# How to find near exp products in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have Table :

| ID | EXP |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 04-FEB-24 |
| 2 | 04-FEB-24 |

And I want the results show in Date before **exp** Date about 1 mouth
EX:

| ID | EXP |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 04-JAN-24 |
| 2 | 04-JAN-24 |

Thanks, you .. i hope you kind

Comment: What happens on March 31?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ADD_MONTHS](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/add_months.php) function. It will be something like this:

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(EXP, -1) as new_date from Table;
```